# How to print the right name in the code below?

Tags: javascript

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    if (i % 15 === 0 || i % 10 === 0) {
           console.log("Donkey!");
          
        } else if  (i % 2 !== 0 && (i - 1) % 10 === 0)  {
            console.log("Monkey!");
        } else if (i % 7 === 0) {
          continue;
        } else {
          console.log(i);
        }
  }
```

*emphasized text*If the number is not divisible by 2 and the previous number is divisible by 10, How do I print **Monkey!**?

Comment: You need to post the code you have written.

Comment: Oh, sorry ! I thought that I already posted the code.

Comment: The problem:  1. Print the numbers 1 through 50.
    
.2 If the number is divisible by 7, you must skip the next number.
    
3. If the number is divisible by 10 or 15, you must print “Donkey!”
4. If the number is not divisible by 2 and the previous number is divisible by 10, you must print “Monkey!”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a very random question with no context but has a rather simple solution. Use modulus check if the remainder of the current number divided by 2 is not 0 and check if the remainder of the last number divided by 10 is 0:

```js
function check(n) {
    if (n % 2 !== 0 && (n - 1) % 10 === 0) {
      console.log('Monkey!');
    } 
}
check(11)
```

Comment: Note: If "previous number" _does_ mean `n - 1`, then it is sufficient to only check for `(n - 1) % 10 === 0` as `n % 2 !=== 0` will automatically follow.